# Multiple text fields with id's in django

Tags: python, django

I want to process multiple fields in django. In PHP I'm using generated HTML like:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield[1]" />
<input type="text" name="myfield[4]" />
<input type="text" name="myfield[5]" />
```

Where the number in brackets is id from db (cookies or other source).
When I process this form, I can get values from `$_POST['my field']` array by keys (1, 4, 5 in example).

I want to know, how can I do same thing in django and how to handle such multiple fields?
I've created a list of checkboxes before. There I can store id in value of checkbox field, but it doesn't work with textfield, because in value I need value sent by user.

UPD:
I'm new with Django and Python (started Django just a few weeks ago).
models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Order(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    exhibition = models.ForeignKey(Exhibition)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    ordered = models.IntegerField()

class Exhibition(models.Model):
    play = models.ForeignKey(Play)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

view

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from tickets.forms import CourierForm

def play_info_courier(request, pk):
    data = get_object_or_404(Exhibition, pk=pk)
    CourierFormSet = modelformset_factory(CourierForm, extra=0)
    orders = Order.objects.filter(exhibition=data).values()
    formset = CourierFormSet(initial=orders)
    context = RequestContext(request, {'data': data, 'formset': formset})
    return render_to_response('tickets/courier.html', context)
```

forms

```
class CourierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.name != 'id' %}
                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endif %}
            <tr>
                <!-- here is my problem, how can I get username from User
                or anything else from other related models? -->
                <td>{{ form.user.username }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.category.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.date.value }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.ordered }}</td>
            </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" name="order" value="Order"/>
<input type="submit" name="clean" value="Clean order"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, you use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/) to implement such scenarios.

Example view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(label='id', widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    value = forms.CharField(label='value')

TestFormSet = formset_factory(TestForm, extra=0)

def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fs = TestFormSet(request.POST)
    else:
        fs = TestFormSet(initial=[
            dict(id=1, value='foo'),
            dict(id=4, value='bar'),
            dict(id=5, value='baz'),
        ])
    context = {
        'fs': fs,
    }
    return render(request, 'formset/test.html', context)
```

`formset/test.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ fs.management_form }}
            {% for form in fs %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div>{{ field }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        {{ fs.cleaned_data }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Example submitted data (`fs.cleaned_data`):

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'value': u'foo'
    },
    {
        'id': 4,
        'value': u'bar'
    },
    {
        'id': 5,
        'value': u'baz'
    }
]
```

---

### Model Formsets

With model formsets, you [cannot generally supply the `initial` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) as you do with regular formsets — the `initial` values will only apply to the `extra` forms, not to the ones associated with actual instances of your model.

When you do this:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(exhibition=data).values()
formset = CourierFormSet(initial=orders)
```

you likely mean this:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(exhibition=data)
formset = CourierFormSet(queryset=orders)
```

This will instantiate a formset with forms for all instances returned by `Order.objects.filter(exhibition=data)`. After that, each form in the formset will have an `instance` attribute, holding the actual `Order` instance bound to that form:

```
<td>{{ form.instance.user.username }}</td>
```

Note that there are some other issues with your code:

1. You're only rendering the first form in the formset, because you do it inside a `{% if forloop.first %}` block; this is unlikely to be what you really want to accomplish.
2. You're skipping over the `id` fields of the form; this will dissociate your submitted form data from your initial model instances — you want those as hidden fields, which is automatically done by the formset when you render the `id` fields.
3. The first parameter of `modelformset_factory` is expected to be the
   *model* class, not the form class; you probably mean `CourierFormSet = modelformset_factory(Order, form=CourierForm, extra=0)`.

Comment: I tried formsets, but I have difficulty with it. 
When I needed to get the column value from the associated model. I still don't understand how to get it. For example models `Order` and `User`. How can i get username for order, when using queryset initial data in formset?

Comment: I've posted a complete working example of using formsets, although not _model_ formsets. If you post your attempts to use formsets, I might be able to help you with it.

Comment: I added the code in question. Sorry, the code can not be entirely true, since I removed part of it, when I gave up trying to make a form from a table in formset. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
request.POST.getlist('myfield')
```

Comment: in this case getlist will return None.

Comment: And even if it did work, it would not associate the text inputs with their respective IDs in any way.